# Form Value Relation Dropdown QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I want to create an attribute-form that displays some fields in value-related dropdowns. The goal is to **limit the options in the second dropdown dependent upon the selection in the first dropdown**. In my case, I have the following two fields that should be related:

1. List "Schwachstelle" with attributes **ID** (PK) and Name
2. List "Schwachstelle_spez" with attributes ID (PK), Name and **ID_Schwachstelle**

The key-attributes between the two lists are the **ID** of "Schwachstelle" and **ID_Schwachstelle** of "Schwachstelle_spez".

The filter I wrote for the value-dependent dropdown ("Schwachstelle_spez")  is the following:

```
"ID" = current_value( 'Schwachstelle_ID' )
```

However, this does still show all possible values in the "related" dropdown.

(I took https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8shIZrwlQt4 as an example)

This is what the layer, where I specify the Dropdown-values, looks like: [image: no image description]

And this is the layer, on which the upper layer is dependent on: [image: no image description]

Attribute table of "Schwachstelle": [image: no image description]

Attribute table of "Schwachstelle_spez": [image: no image description]

If the user were to choose "Nutzungskonflikte", "Umwege" would **not** apperar in the following dropdown.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: This should be possible by simply defining the value-relations in the attribute-table in the layer-properties of the qfield-project. So, there's no code except for the filter-expression.

Comment: As far as I know, QGIS does not support depending lists. So I am afraid you have to write your own code. I have the same task...

Comment: Your filter looks ok, how does your lookup table/value relation layer look like?

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots above.

Comment: A duplicate question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/386018/35561

Answer (score 1):

Try ' instead of " for the current_value()-argument within your filter-criterion. This should work:

`"ID" = current_value('Schwachstelle_ID')`