# Getting value from another table using Form-Qgis

Tags: qgis, valuerelation

I am creating this form.

[image]

But here I need to create a filter expression using by a field that is in another table. When the field is in the same table , I usually use an expression like this:

```
"my_field"  =  current_value( 'field_same_table')
```

but here I need something like this:

```
"my_field"  =  current_value( 'field_another_table') ---- (my own syntax)
```

I tried this: current_parent_value, but it did not work.

I have read about this function:  `attribute (get_feature () )`

Comment: Possibly a similar question (and answer?) to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/470633/automatically-populate-a-field-on-a-form-from-a-lookup-table-depending-on-what-i/470710#470710